# Conversion from long to int gives another number?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My program was crashed, because i was trying to go into array with `76 objects` with index 128 .
After the crash i put the mouse on some variables, and see what their value was in the crash and i see something strange .

```
if(cell.tag>-1 && cell.tag<[mainData count])
{
 [self loadMainImageToIndex:(int)cell.tag];
}
```

So here, i can see that  `[mainData count]` is in size of 76 .
Than i go into the function :

```
-(void)loadMainImageToIndex:(int)index
```

And the `index` value is `128` .

**But** , if it is `128` , that means the the first condition here, couldn't be true because 128 is higher than 76, and due to this, the function being called with 128 .

That means, that `cell.tag` in the condition , was lower than 76 , and `(int)cell.tag` is 128..
??

Comment: After the crash all bets are off: the stack is in a screwed up state, so the debugger is going to show junk. You need to catch it in the debugger before the crash.

Comment: actually i can open the array and see the right values that are expected to be there ..

Comment: `NSArray` is different, its data is in the heap area, which does not generally get screwed up after a crash (at least it's not a guaranteed wipe-out, like it is with the stack).

Comment: Ok thanks, nice to know that , so if it might not be screwed up, how can i get this value ?

Comment: To catch the value set a breakpoint in `loadMainImageToIndex:`. However, there may be too many hits, so it might be simpler to assure yourself that your problem is elsewhere. Add these lines inside the `if`: `int tmp = (int)cell.tag; NSAssert(tmp >= 0 && tmp < [mainData count], @"Index is out of bounds");` and run your program again. If the assertion is triggered, you caught your culprit; if the assertion is not triggered, this portion of your code is fine, and it's something else.

Comment: Can you add the declaration of you `mainData`? array.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks very much, the problem is happens rarely and i can't catch it but i will try that . The declaration is at the start with mainData=[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; than adding views to it.